# How to get array data in a single array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 23 [4] => 5 [5] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 2 )
```

So I have this array. I want the all data in a single array like this.How to achieve this.

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 23 [4] => 5 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 2 [10] => 3 [11] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 1, 23, 4, 2];
$array2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2];

var_dump(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should juste combine those two array using the [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function like this

```
$array1 = [1,2,1,23,5,2];

$array2 = [1,1,1,2,3,2];

$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: I mean the array list is huge. I just showed the two examples. Can't do that using ur method. Have to use loop I guess.

Comment: you can use still use `array_merge` as you can pass in as many array you want to merge, It doesn't receive two parameters, it can be 3, 4, 5, etc. It's up to you depending on the number of array you want to merge

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the array_merge function provided by PHP.
For example, the code

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

will produce the following output:

```
[color] => green
[0] => 2
[1] => 4
[2] => a
[3] => b
[shape] => trapezoid
[4] => 4
```

If you don't want to overwrite any data, you can simply use the + operator,
For example, the code

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($result);
```

will produce:

```
  [0]=>
  string(6) "zero_a"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "two_a"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "three_a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "one_b"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "four_b"
```

Source:

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use spread opertaor in javascript :

```
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const array2 = [6,7,8,9,10];

const array3 = [...array1,...arry2];
conole.log(array3);
//output : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = [ 1, 2, 1, 23, 4, 2 ];
$arr2 = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2 ];
$arr3 = [ 30, 31, 32 ];
$arrOfArrays = [
    [ 40, 41 ],
    [ 50, 51 ]
];

$result = [ ...$arr1, ...$arr2, ...$arr3, ...array_merge(...$arrOfArrays) ];

print_r($result);
```

This will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 21
    [4] => 22
    [5] => 30
    [6] => 31
    [7] => 32
    [8] => 40
    [9] => 41
    [10] => 50
    [11] => 51
    [12] => 52
)
```